# Issues with Apache and Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm, trying to run both MediaWiki and Wordpress on an Apache server. I've got the MediaWiki site set up with a couple of sub-domain Virtual Hosts, so everything is fine there. This is installed at `/var/www/html/mediawiki`.

I'm trying to install Wordpress on it's own directory, `/var/www/wordpress`.
In my config file for Wordpress' virtual host, I've got:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/wordpress/>    AllowOverride All</Directory>
```

Obviously domain.com is not the domain.

Whenever I visit domain.com, however, it seems to be loading the MediaWiki install from `/var/www/html/mediawiki`, which is obviously not what I want.

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: please post the access.log entries. By default Apache will enter the first Virt. Host in the config file if none of the ServerNames oder VirtHost definitions match. That might be the problem in your case.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/name-based.html   "If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then the first listed virtual host that matches that will be used"

Comment: Something has to be different between your VirtualHost blocks for Apache to know which one you want.  You cannot have both listen on port 80, with the same ServerName.  As you did not show both VirtualHost, I cannot give an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run apachectl to see all the servers/vhosts running on your server both port 80 and 443

```
apachectl -S
```

Also I believe that:

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/>    AllowOverride All</Directory>
```

should be inside of your virtual host block